# Javascript Iterate json by index

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to write a loop to access an element of this json array directly, I've used a few examples found on here and elsewhere which show iterating of json data, but I haven't got any to work whilst also using indexes.

http://jsfiddle.net/rfVGW/

I've been looking to do the following within a loop, my actually json is on a single line (see jsfiddle):

```
alert(jsonData.data[0].serviceType);
```

readable json string

```
{
"data": [{
    "id": "1",
    "serviceType": "test",
    "firstName": "",
    "lastName": "",
    "address1": "",
    "address2": "",
    "address3": "",
    "city": "",
    "county": "",
    "postCode": "",
    "website": "",
    "latitude": "",
    "longitude": "",
    "phoneArr": ["00001", "000002"]
}, {
    "id": "1",
    "serviceType": "",
    "firstName": "",
    "lastName": "",
    "address1": "",
    "address2": "",
    "address3": "",
    "city": "",
    "county": "",
    "postCode": "",
    "website": "",
    "latitude": "",
    "longitude": "",
    "phoneArr": ["00001", "000002"]
}]
}
```

Comment: What is the issue? Is it a string coming back and if so are you doing a JSON.parse? `JSON.parse(jsonData).data[0].serviceType`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rfVGW/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rfVGW/2/)

You are not parsing the variable to JSON.

So please do it by using **JSON.parse();**

```
var par = JSON.parse(jsonData);
alert(par.data[0].serviceType);
```

Comment: Thank you Naveen, I wasnt aware that I needed to use JSON.parse. I had presumed that when setting a variable with json data javscript would automatically assume a json type.

Comment: @kirgy - JSON.parse() doesn't exist on older browsers.  And... Thank goodness JavaScript **doesn't** automatically attempt to parse every single string to check if its valid JSON (and convert it if it is)... That would be horrific.  You should really do a little research before making such an assumptions and/or asking a question (that's been asked so many times).  Here's a [JSON tutorial](http://www.json.org/js.html). Here's the [MDN JSON page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JSON).